# Why logs contains null characters(holes) using logback

Tags: java, logging, logback

I am using logback(SiftingAppender and RollingFileAppender) in my application. Whenever requests come in, they will be logged to different files according to the id from url query.

This is working really well and I get the expected result. However, I noticed occasionally, there are some null characters in the middle of logs. I am not sure why this happens and how to reduce it.

I did some research and the closest thing I found is https://serverfault.com/questions/71341/why-do-jboss-and-logrotate-create-log-files-full-of-nul-characters

They are using logrotate with log4j and that results in the null character. However, in my case, the whole log rotate and lifecycle is handled by logback.

This is partial of my logback xml configuration:

```
<appender name="SIFT" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.SiftingAppender">
<discriminator>
  <key>id</key>
  <defaultValue>main</defaultValue>
</discriminator>
<sift>
  <appender name="${id}Rolling" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <fileNamePattern>${logRoot}/${id}.%d{"yyyy-MM-dd-HH", UTC}.%i.json</fileNamePattern>
      <maxFileSize>${logSizeLimit}</maxFileSize>
      <maxHistory>100</maxHistory>
      <totalSizeCap>20GB</totalSizeCap>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>
</sift>
```

And in the java code:

```
String jsonOutput = gson.toJson(ping);

MDC.put("id", id));
logger.info(jsonOutput);
MDC.remove("id");
```

The output log looks like :

{"timestamp":{"seconds":1557048143,"nanos":028000000},"httpRequest":{"status":200,"remoteIp":"111.11.111.111","requestMethod":"GET","requestUrl":"https://my.example.com/?id=testid","userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 "}}
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@{"timestamp":{"seconds":1557041043,"nanos":318000000},"httpRequest":{"status":200,"remoteIp":"111.11.111.111","requestMethod":"GET","requestUrl":"https://my.example.com/?id=testid","userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 "}}

I am using vim to open it, so it displays null character as ^@. These null characters are appended at the beginning of a real log message. I haven't found a pattern when this will happen. I am expecting normal logs without these null characters.

Answer (score 0):

While log rotation can cause certain problems, I'd like to present an alternative cause (and solution) for the effects you are seeing. I had similar problems with log4j2.

I suspect that garbled output (null characters) in the log file is related to *thread safety*. While low-level POSIX routines (ex. printf) are thread-safe that cannot be claimed for direct filedescriptor access preferred sometimes for performance considerations. It's all about the appender implementation. Using a logger already provides the needed thread safety and asynchronous operation guarantees, thus if a single logging mechanism is used low-level thread safety is not an issue. However this can cause problems the moment multiple logging mechanisms are used.

In applications is pretty easy to end up using multiple logging mechanisms due to transitive dependencies (libraries). So while you may target *logback* or *log4j* some of your dependencies might try to use *commons-logging*. The solution in such cases is pretty easy: just add a bridge implementation to *commons-logging* or some other logging mechanism used by the imported library.